# cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'AppHdr'

Tags: xml, xsd, pentaho

I got a problem with validating xml file against xsd.
I tried to validate my xml via XML validator component (transformation) in Pentaho PDI 9.3.
The problem is that result of validation in PDI is failed and return:
cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'AppHdr'

AppHdr is the first tag inside the head.001 part of xml

But when I validated my xml in notepad++, its says that file is correct.

As you can see below, the xsd contains two xml's inside, one that's the header (head.003), and other one with the message.

Here's the xml for head.003:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BizData xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.003.001.01"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <Hdr >
      <AppHdr xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.01"
              xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.01 head.001.001.01.xsd">
         <Fr >
            <OrgId>
               <Id>
                  <OrgId>
                     <Othr>
                        <Id>DMBOS</Id>
                        <SchmeNm>
                           <Cd>COD</Cd>
                        </SchmeNm>
                        <Issr>Issr</Issr>
                     </Othr>
                  </OrgId>
               </Id>
            </OrgId>
         </Fr>
         <To >
            <OrgId>
               <Id>
                  <OrgId>
                     <Othr>
                        <Id>DMBOS</Id>
                        <SchmeNm>
                           <Cd>COD</Cd>
                        </SchmeNm>
                        <Issr>Issr</Issr>
                     </Othr>
                  </OrgId>
               </Id>
            </OrgId>
         </To>
         <BizMsgIdr >BizMsgIdr</BizMsgIdr>
         <MsgDefIdr >MsgDefIdr</MsgDefIdr>
         <CreDt >2024-01-12T15:10:50.073Z</CreDt>
      </AppHdr>
   </Hdr>
   <Pyld >
      <Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:auth.108.001.01"
                xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:auth.108.001.01 auth.108.001.01.xsd">
         <DerivsTradMrgnDataRpt >
            <RptHdr>
               <NbRcrds>-418680</NbRcrds>
            </RptHdr>
            <TradData>
               <DataSetActn>NOTX</DataSetActn>
            </TradData>
         </DerivsTradMrgnDataRpt>
      </Document>
   </Pyld>
</BizData>
```

And the xsd:

```
<xs:schema xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.003.001.01" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.003.001.01">
    <xs:element name="BizData" type="BusinessDataHeaderV01"/>
    <xs:complexType name="BusinessApplicationHeaderEnvelope">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:any namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.01" processContents="strict"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="BusinessDataHeaderV01">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Hdr" type="BusinessApplicationHeaderEnvelope"/>
            <xs:element name="Pyld" type="StrictPayload"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="StrictPayload">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:any namespace="##any" processContents="strict"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Tried validation in other sources, notepad++ validates corect when all xmls and xsds are put in one directory.

PDI doesnt provide more info on that error.

Comment: Please add to your question two missing XSD files: (1) head.001.001.01.xsd, and (2) auth.108.001.01.xsd Without them it is impossible to discern what causing the errors.

Comment: `processContents="strict"` requires that the element be declared; nothing you've posted shows a declaration for `AppHdr `, thus the error.  Either change `processContents` to a more relaxed setting (see duplicate link), or post a [mcve] that includes a declaration of `AppHdr` and ask why the declaration is not being found.